# Umbraco deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, umbraco, umbraco7

I just created a website in vstudio 2017 and added Umbracocms Nuget package. I also added uSync, made some configuration, design and so on, then I published the site to Azure. Before publishing, I modified my web.config to be sure to force the wizard to fire. Therefore, I could configure my Sql Azure database and now the site works like a charm.

No, I'm thinking about future update... To be able to continue to develop the site on my local machine, I had to revert my web.config to use the SDF file, so what will happen for the next deployment on Azure ? I guess that the web.config file will be in the package, so it will replace the one on Azure.

So either, I always clear the keys to force the wizard to run, or I don't and then I guess my site will go down because it won't be using the SQL Azure database anymore.

What's the solution for this? How can I **update** my site on Azure seamlessly? In my mind, I would just have to click on "Publish", then, the site gets uploaded on Azure, uSync ensure the changes I made are synchronized and that's it.

Comment: you can have a cloud web config and a local web config. if you are always connecting to sql azure even during development you dont have to do anything for the db. if not you can have a SQL DB project to maintain the changes that you do to your db in the course of development.

Comment: Well, I would like to use the sdf file in development and the sql Azure db in production (I don’t want to alter live data in development), but let say that I modify a lot of files in my project. In order to be sure that I don’t forget any, I’d do a publish of the project, so the web.config would get overridden.

Comment: you can publish your db afresh every time. that should not be an issue. as far as web config is concerned apart from the db connection string do you have too many variables? in that case you can use web config transformations using xslt.

Comment: I don’t get it. It’s not about being too many variable, it’s just that as I want to use the sdf file in local, the web.config will always be overwritten when I do a publish at project level. And I’d like not to have to run the wizard every time I do such a deployment.

Comment: publish db separately from SQL management studio and site from visual studio. Or you can explore UaaS - umbraco cloud service if you have not done already.

Comment: Sorry, it’s really not what I want. Looks like web config transformation is what I’m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you deploy the site you will either want to use Web.Config Transformations **AND** configure Visual Studio's Publish settings.

You should already have a Web.Config and a Web.Release.Config.

In Web.Config you will have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <remove name="umbracoDbDSN" />
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="your local connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then in Web.Release.Config you will want to have:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="umbracoDbDSN"
         connectionString="your production connection string" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
</connectionStrings>
```

In your publish profile you can then set the configuration to release. When you do so you will also notice umbracoDbDSN show up with an empty textbox. In my experience it is best to also put the connection string from Web.Release.Config in there and check "Use this connection string at runtime".

This extra transformation gets applied after the transformations in Web.Release.config and will overwrite them. Historically this interface has been a bit buggy and has been known to wipe out connection strings if it's not explicitly set.